# Modular arithmetic for negative numbers proof

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm working through some modular arithmetic for cryptography. I have a (probably simple) proof that I want to work through. The problem is this:

Prove that

$$(-a)\text{ mod }m = m - (a \text{ mod }m)$$

My instinct is to separate the -1 and a like this:

$$(-a)\text{ mod }m = ((-1) \text{ mod }m)*(a \text{ mod }m)$$

I then wrote $a$ and $-1$ as:
$$-1 =  m*q_1 + r_1$$
$$a = m*q_2+r_2$$

By substituting the values in I get a polynomial like:

$$(-a)\text{ mod } m = (m*q_1*m*q_2+m*q_1*r_2 +r_1*m*q_2 +r_1*r_2) \text{ mod } m$$
then factoring out $m$ gives
$$(-a)\text{ mod } m = (m*(q_1*m*q_2+q_1*r_2 +r_1*q_2) +r_1*r_2) \text{ mod } m$$
I then jump to (this seems like some missing steps)
$$(-a)\text{ mod } m = (r_1*r_2) \text{ mod } m$$

I don't seem to be getting where I need to be with this. It looks like I'm missing some steps or maybe not thinking this through correctly.

Can anyone give me a hint on how this might be done?

Comment: From your equality do you have $(-a)\text{ mod }m +(a \text{ mod }m)= m $ and remember that $m=0$ mod $m$. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of $c \bmod m$?  One version is to use the division algorithm to write $c=qm+d$ where $d \in [0,m-1]$ Then if $a \bmod m=b$ you have $-a=-qm-b=-(q-1)m+(m-b)$ where $m-b \in [0,m-1]$